Designing a 4 H-bridge PCB board using a DRV8871
I want to make a 4 H-bridge PCB that consists of 4 DRV8871. I have seen the schematic that Adafruit has posted for their design and looks suitable for my case. So my idea was to repeat their module 4 times.

I have also noticed that they are using a 22uF/63v Capacitor. When I read the datasheet of the DRV8871, one of the requirements was a bulk capacitor which this one represents.

Now my question is:
Is it necessary to repeat the capacitor for each drv8871 or I can I just install one for all of them instead?


It depends on your motors, pcb design and power supply. The bulk capacitance is there to supply peak currents. I’d play it safe and use 1 per chip. You main choice is electrolytic caps as properly sized ceramic caps to work at 45V will be physically large and a little pricey - the critical spec is the voltage derating. The higher the voltage, the less the actual capacitance. Don’t use tantalum as they do not like transients that a motor load would give - they like to go up in flames (literally).
